# CSS technique for a horizontal line between two words

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to add a horizontal line in the middle of two words. For example:

First word ----------------------------------- Second word

Is there a way to do that in CSS or flex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm providing a solution using Flexbox because I didn't see one from the link in @Awais's comment above.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container .middle {
  margin: 0 5px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-bottom: 1px dashed;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>First word</span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span>Second word</span>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6syot39h/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS Flex solution with minimal line of code.

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
}

.middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-self: center;
}

.dash {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>First word</div>
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="dash"></div>
  </div>
  <div>Second word</div>
</div>
```